# How to make android application reinstall after hard reset?

Tags: java, android, web

We are trying to create a Final Year Project for android that is based upon remote access of your phone in case you forget or loose it.

The web page has further modules for communicating with our android application for stuff like SMS, Camera, Microphone, Call Logs (Call routing not possible due to restriction with telephony stack if it is please do mention that as well).

Now as we are handling the theft case as well we are facing one of the biggest challenges that how to keep our application installed even after a hard reset of phone. It is clear that the application needs to be a system application for that and must be pre-installed on the android phone. The question we are trying to ask is that is it somehow possible to install our application via web through some google service that trigger some event on our web server and it further installs the application back onto phone.

I am sorry for asking a troubling and not so good formatted question. Currently I am unable to find anything on android developer page and many other sites like XDA.

Further more can we try to create some script on recovery of android so that application is installed automatically when the system gets reset.

Thanks

Comment: I guess this is not possible . After all automatic triggering can be possible only if your browser link somehow detects if app is installed or not. Ideally user needs to reinstall app and according to your logic during startup, need to check and initiate conditions

Comment: If this was possible, Android security would be worth nothing

Comment: Thanks everyone that is what I figured out but was thinking if there was a way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little late to answer the following question but I have completed my project and so I wanted to add a few things to the answer here.
I was able to complete the idea of theft side by making our application use [Device Administrators](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). With that we were able to detect the number of times a pattern is entered wrong and on the third wrong try, the application would take up the Picture from the front camera through a service and then the picture from the back camera is optional moreover it also synchronizes the current location with the server.

Device Administrator also offered a feature to reset your android device and we were able to perform a reset remotely or on some conditions that are set by the user. That still persisted the problem that the application would also be uninstalled. There are some tricks to make that work but only on a rooted phone but that would also make the whole effort of theft prevention at risk too. Someone technical may completely reset our application's recovery scripts by entering the recovery mode which is not password protected. So yes there are no proper ways to do that.

To the last point which is still conceptual and I did very little work on that was to forward the phone calls. As the system doesn't support it there was a lot of lag in the technique I used. The idea was to completely go in a new direction.

The first step was to write a call recorder which is possible so we did write one that would not write the data to the file instead would send the data over the stream on the network. The next step was transmitting back the user's voice now that was not a clean solution but the sent stream to the android from the web was played directly on the phone's speaker as a media file which was amplified so yes that was not a good way to transmit back the voice on the phone back to the person on the other end would be hearing a lot of garble and this also had a lot of lag but was worth the try and fun.

Code will soon be on git for opensource development and improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot install application without the user input/interaction. There is only way if the user chooses to reinstall application. In case of recovery, if the user had created a backup and synced with the google account then the app may get installed automatically as android asks to recover the contacts, data, and apps from user's google account.